# if multiple threads are updating the same variable, what should be done so each thread updates the variable correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading

If multiple threads are updating the same variable, what should I do so each thread updates the variable correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this a general question, or do you have a specific problem? In many cases, multiple threads updating the same variable is not a good pattern.

Comment: I'm assuming she's studying for something....preferably a java exam.

Comment: @Mike Caron: and the 3 who upvoted this comment not addressing the question... A question on SO is a question on SO and the question here is perfectly formulated (maybe even a little bit too perfectly, for it looks like a textbook question). SO is **not** about questioning every single question. SO is about on-topicly answering legitimate questions.  I'm getting sick about all these *"I'm on my high-horse, I know better than you, you should use pattern 'z' "* type of comments upvoted on SO.

Comment: @SpoonBender: I'm not preaching to anyone. I'm trying to determine whether to answer the question literally or in a more general sense. Even worse than the people "on high horses" are the people who _are on high horses about other people being on high horses_. The mind boggles.

Answer (score 9):

There are several options:

1) **Using no synchronization at all**

This can only work if the data is of primitive type (not long/double), and you don't care about reading stale values (which is unlikely)

2) **Declaring the field as volatile**

This will guarantee that stale values are never read. It also works fine for objects (assuming the objects aren't changed after creation), because of the happens-before guarantees of volatile variables (See "Java Memory Model").

3) **Using java.util.concurrent.AtomicLong, AtomicInteger etc**

They are all thread safe, and support special operations like atomic incrementation and atomic compare-and-set operations.

4) **Protecting reads and writes with the same lock**

This approach provides mutual exclusion, which allows defining a large atomic operation, where multiple data members are manipulated as a single operation.

Answer (score 5):

This is a major problem with multi-threaded applications, and spans more than I could really cover in an answer, so I'll point you to some resources.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#concurrencyjava_synchronized

Essentially, you use the `synchronized` keyword to place a lock around a variable.  This makes sure that the piece of code is only being run once at a time.  You can also place locks around the same object in multiple areas.

Additionally, you need to look out for several pitfalls, such as Deadlock.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/deadlock.html

Errors caused by misuse of locks are often very difficult to debug and track down, because they aren't very consistent.  So, you always need to be careful that you put all of your locks in the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement locking on the variable in question.
Eg.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html